# Domain controller IP address change

Tags: networking, server, samba

Sorry if my question sounds obvious, but I'm getting started here.

I wanted to change my recently configured Domain Controller's static IP on Ubuntu 14.04.4, Samba 4.4.4 since I experienced some instability (was using 192.168.1.16 address). So, I changed it to 192.168.1.100 in /etc/network/interfaces and in /etc/hosts and restarted samba, but when I try to test Kerberos using kinit administrator@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL, I get the following message:

kinit cannot contact any KDC for realm 'MYDOMAIN.LOCAL' while getting initial credentials

My Windows machine which could access the DC before no longer can as well.

Investigating, I got this out of `nslookup mydcserver.mydomain.local`:

```
Server:        192.168.1.100
Address:       192.168.1.100#53

Name:     mydcserver.mydomain.local
Address:  192.168.1.16  <---- Former address!
```

ifconfig gives:

```
p2p1    ...
        inet addr: 192.168.1.100  Bcast: 192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

So, where nslookup got this old address? I guess this explains why my DC is no longer reachable?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain here but I think you are having issues with name resolution.

You will need to update the IP address the domain name `mydcserver.mydomain.local` points to.

[Here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/DNS_administration) is the link to the samba documentation on administering DNS records. I would propose that you need to delete the existing record for your domain controller and then add a new record pointing to the updated address.

Leave any comments and ill try and assist where I can!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Dan turnip! I'm stun right now. If for instance I want query the zone lists through 'samba-tool dns zonelist myserver', I get the follwoing: 'Failed to connect to host 192.168.1.16 on port 135...'. Then if I want to query for the records through 'samba-tool dns query localhost mydomain.local @ ALL -U Administrator', I have this: 'A: 192.168.1.100' all the rest of the content of the record is fine.